# log4net error in NUnit: "Attempted to append to closed appender named []."

Tags: nunit, log4net

When I run some integration tests via NUnit, everything works, including logging.  When I run any test *a second time*, no exception is thrown, but logging ceases to work.  Instead, log4net writes this to the console:

```
log4net:ERROR [TextWriterAppender] Attempted to append to closed appender named [].
```

Here is the log4net configuration:

```
  <log4net debug="true" >
    <appender name="console"
          type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender, log4net">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
        <param name="ConversionPattern"
             value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
      <priority value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>

    <logger name="NHibernate">
      <level value="WARN" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="NHibernate.SQL" >
      <level value="DEBUG" />
    </logger>
  </log4net>
```

The setup code is in a static constructor in the SUT:

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

I managed to get the same error with a variety of other appender settings.  What causes this error?  I want to know what the cause is so I know how to fix it, and also how to reproduce this in a production scenario (if that is possible) so I can keep it from happening to production code.

I am using NHibernate 2.0.1.GA and the log4net version that comes with it (1.2.10.0).

Comment: Can you show the test that throws the exception?

Comment: The test does not throw an exception, and no exception is caught in the SUT (the code being tested).  This problem seems to happen with every test that performs any CRUD operation via NHibernate.  I don't know if the problem is limited to the NHibernate.Sql logger, or if the NHibernate logger also experiences this problem; I'll dig into that.

Comment: But it would help to have the test code so that we can reproduce the NHibernate calls that interact with log4net.

Answer (score 2):

Well if you look at the error it says [TextWriterAppender] this means log4net is trying to to append the log message to a TextWriter whereas the config which you gave doesn't have any.

Either there is another config file with a log4net tag being loaded or in code you are anywhere calling up LogManager.Shutdown()